# Typedef, Violation of ODR: same keyword alias different types

Tags: c, typedef, one-definition-rule

I need to link 2 libraries. The first library requires a header file in which:

```
typedef int TYPE
```

The second library requires a header file in which:

```
typedef struct type TYPE
```

Obviously linking them results in a violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR). The obvious solution here is to rename one of the types. However, this will require me to change that in hundreds of files too, which I'm trying to avoid because it will make all of our projects inconsistent.
Is there any other way to overcome this issue?

Comment: How will changing all the files make the project inconsistent?

Comment: @mafso for instance, project1 uses the keyword TYPE, while this project would use _TYPE, although they are both alias the same type

Comment: Only if you don't change the hundreds of files. I'm not sure what you want. Either the same type is called the same in the entire project consistently (which means refactoring in your case) or you only want different identifiers in the files using both `TYPE`s (which means you can leave your hundreds of files unchanged but makes the project inconsistent).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If library A has the header file `header_a.h` and library B has header file `header_b.h` you can do something like this as a workaround in source code forms that have to include both:

```
#define TYPE TYPE_A
#include <header_a.h>
#undef TYPE

#define TYPE TYPE_B
#include <header_b.h>
#undef TYPE
```

This causes the declarations

```
typedef int TYPE;          /* from library A */
typedef struct type TYPE;  /* from library B */
```

to appear as

```
typedef int TYPE_A;
typedef struct type TYPE_B;
```

This should work fine as type information is not present in object file. Nonetheless, the header files from libraries A and B might do weird stuff with macros that break with these definitions, so you should check for that before.